# Difference in energy required between flying Verically vs flying in the same horizontal plane

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, energy, fluid-dynamics, aerodynamics

> An insect of mass 150mg is hovering. What would be the energy required to fly straight up 10cm (against gravitational force) vs forward 10cm?
>
> Weight of insect:150mg
> Displacement:10cm

I want to know the difference in energy required between flying Verically vs flying in the same horizontal plane. Assume the insect is already hovering.

Answer (score 0):

The energy required to fly vertically upwards will be equal to the change in potential energy of the insect, and the energy required to fly horizontally will be zero if we assume that the frictional losses are zero, which is probably the assumption in this problem.